# does "open to charges of" equal to "doing propaganda" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

> Always **open to charges of** propaganda and interference in the internal affairs of other nations, public diplomacy challenged both the spirit and letter of the Havana Convention.
>
> [Book | Diplomacy: A Very Short Introduction](https://books.google.com/books?id=i0sTiwJQMi0C&pg=PT29&lpg=PT29&dq=Always+**open+to+charges+of**+propaganda+and+interference+in+the+internal+affairs+of+other+nations&source=bl&ots=0eqkwi-N3L&sig=f0UG3tZKG3r8zT5WyLIj4bPo5YM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4yKSPkvjLAhXJNSYKHSZoCX4Q6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=Always%20**open%20to%20charges%20of**%20propaganda%20and%20interference%20in%20the%20internal%20affairs%20of%20other%20nations&f=false)

As far as I understand, it means:

A charge placed against a defendant, usually to enable the police to gain time for the discovery of further evidence, so that another more serious charge may be made.

But it is not appropriate.

Comment: 'Open to charges of' means '[Quite] likely to be charged with'.

Comment: "Charge" does have the meaning you describe in a judicial or law enforcement context, but it can also mean more generally "a statement of complaint or hostile criticism" ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charge)), which is how it is used in your example sentence.

Comment: Hi @yorgun.  I want to invite you, and everyone commenting/answering/voting here, to participate in [this meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/7916/13804)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, **open to charges of** could be reworded as **vulnerable to accusations of**.

Yes the phrase has a slightly different meaning in a legal context but a glance at the book tells me this is about contrasting public diplomacy vs official diplomacy.  Since public diplomacy isn't private sometimes things are said to other countries mostly to be heard by one's own country.

Comment: it means public diplomacy is vulnerable to accusations of propaganda.